# Как сделать подобную html разметку? Адаптивно

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Ширина макета 1300px. Как сделать под 1300 я еще понимаю, но как это сделать адаптивным под любой размер вплоть до 320px не знаю...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ , http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: данный вопрос-картинку следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний: идеи, выраженные картинками, поисковики (пока) не умеют индексировать.

Comment: @alexander barakin как, закрыть вопрос? Кнопка "Удалить"? Написано мол "Мы не рекомендуем удалять вопросы, на которые даны ответы."

Comment: @Александр, уже закрыт. 22 часа назад. это написано сразу под текстом вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите в стилях относительные размеры, например в % или же sizes="00vw". Также вы можете применять технику art direction, например:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="head.jpg, head-2x.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="head-small.jpg, head-small-2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="head-fb.jpg" srcset="head-fb-2x.jpg 2x" alt="a head carved out of wood">
</picture>
```

Создавайте точки останова для адаптивных изображений, например:

```
<img src="400.png" sizes="(min-width: 600px) 25vw, (min-width: 500px) 50vw, 100vw" srcset="100.png 100w, 200.png 200w, 400.png 400w, 800.png 800w, 1600.png 1600w, 2000.png 2000w" alt="an example image">
```

[**Документация Гугл**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/media/images?hl=ru).